# Web data storage and download services

Tags: ios, download, server, storage, cloudkit

I have an iOS app that currently uses CloudKit to store data. I want to be able to create a download link for each user that if anyone were to go to that link, they would download a piece of data (a small amount) specific to a user. I saw that CloudKit can also be used with the web using CloudKit JS but this would require me to host a server. I was also considering storing each of the user's data in a separate folder on a Dropbox account and then the download link going to that folder but I'm concerned with whether the user would be able to navigate to other folders and download other files.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this (maybe an API) would be much appreciated!